# How to install a plugin in rails 3, getting a Commands is not a module (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install this as a plugin:

```
https://github.com/phatworx/rack_ip_restrictor
```

So I run:

```
$ rails plugin install git://github.com/phatworx/rack_ip_restrictor.git
```

This errors with:

```
/Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/plugin.rb:277:in `<top (required)>': Commands is not a module (TypeError)
    from /Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
    from /Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
    from /Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/activesupport-3.0.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
    from /Users/userme/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Suggestions, ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[There's a solution out on GitHub - check the comments.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1866)

Answer (score 1):

@acconrad is correct. the concrete solution is ( If you use rails 3.0.9- with rake 0.9.2, you should add include Rake::DSL to Rakefile just after require 'rake'.
Then add module Commands; end to script/rails just before require 'rails/commands', you will not get 'Commands is not a module (TypeError)' error message any more.) :

1.in Rakefile,

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'
# add this line of code
include Rake::DSL
```

2.in script/rails:

```
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
# add this line of code
module Commands; end
require 'rails/commands'
```

3.then run this command:

```
$ bundle exec rails plugin install git://github.com/sbecker/asset_packager.git
```

the plugin will be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with rails 3.0.10. It should work with 3.0.10 actually!