# Ruby 1.8.7 + Rails 3.0.20 can't create engine - Commands is not a module (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines, ruby-1.8.7

I want to create an engine for rails app with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.0.20 but when I type:

```
rails plugin new try --full
```

I get:

```
/Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands/plugin.rb:277: Commands is not a module (TypeError)
    from /Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
    from /Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
    from /Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/activesupport-3.0.20/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:242:in `require'
    from /Users/tborisova/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352/gems/railties-3.0.20/lib/rails/commands.rb:17
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a plugin in rails 3, getting a Commands is not a module (TypeError)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112218/how-to-install-a-plugin-in-rails-3-getting-a-commands-is-not-a-module-typeerro)

Comment: This is not duplicate. I don't want to install plugin, I want to create one

Comment: if you read the question carefully, you might find it helpful with your own issue, as i assume it has the same root cause. if so, it does not matter what exactly you are trying to do there.